# To be+ past simple verb

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, linguistics

What is the point in using the structure "To be + past simple verb"?

Example: "For the first time in connection with
the plagues, God specifically noted the discrimination *to be made*—Israel
would be untouched."

Comment: It's a past participle (which in this case is the same as the past simple form, but you'd say eg. "to be done" and not \*"to be did"), and this is just the standard passive voice, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks you! It is very useful.

Comment: *"God specifically noted the discrimination to be made."*  Where did this sentence come from? Did you create it? It doesn't appear to be written by a native English speaker.  If a sentence isn't correctly formed, we can't easily comment on the usage.  I would say that the person who wrote the sentence used it incorrectly.

Comment: The complete phrase is this: "For the first time in connection with
the plagues, God specifically noted the discrimination to be made—Israel
would be untouched."

Comment: is it semmantically incorrect?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, the sentence is grammatically and pragmatically correct.

It seems to be an additional clause with the following meaning:

> God specifically noted the discrimination *( with object )* **that would be made.** *( with that clause)*

A that-clause is common in all sorts of sentences, adding information to whether the subject or the object.

The term is precisely called *"the essential/defining relative/restrictive clause"*, so removing the clause would only provide *"less information" to the reader.*

To clarify, here is another example with "a past participle":

I am done! ( But we can't say: I am did );

We also have some situations where a past participle verb isn't necessarily used with an auxiliary, but still bears its initial meaning and form.

for example

> Looked after carefully, your jacket can last forever! *( = If it is looked after ..... )*

Irregular verbs have different forms of a past participle such as:

- see  -  saw  - seen
- sink - sank  -  sunk